# C# variables inside of quotes

Tags: c#

With string interpolation, how do you handle variables piped into a command that contain spaces in them? For example, if you have a variable that has spaces in it (like a UNC path), how do you handle that?

This code works when no spaces are present in the "filePath" variable (i.e.; \ServerName\testfile.txt):

Ex: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \\{filePath} {pwd /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit();

As soon as you encounter a path that has spaces in it, however, the command above no longer works, because it's unable to find the path. Normally, I would apply quotes around a path containing spaces, to counter this (in other languages like PowerShell). How do you do something similar with C# interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

C# 6.0+:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", @$"use X: \\Servername\share {pwd} /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit();
```

C# < 6.0:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", @"use X: \\Servername\share " + pwd + " /USER: " + usr).WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

use the $

```
void Main()
{
    string pwd = "test";
    var myVar = $"This is a  {pwd}";
    var folder = "MyFolder";
    var myVarWithPaths = $"C:\\{folder}";
    Console.WriteLine(myVar);
    Console.WriteLine(myVarWithPaths);
}
```

Output

> This is a  test
>
> C:\MyFolder

Comment: Thanks, the $ and curly braces worked. Working command is as follows: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \\ServerName\share {pwd} /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit();

Comment: Correction, command is: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \\\\ServerName\\share {pwd} /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit();

Comment: If I'm calling variables inside the curly braces, and if "filePath" and "usr" both contain at least one backslash, how would I write this so the proper number of backslashes are applied? System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \\{filePath} {pwd} /USER:{usr}").WaitForExit(); Note: This command works, when I manually populate text in place of the variables, so I figure it has to be with how C# is converting these variable strings. System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net.exe", $"use X: \\\\ServerName\\share {pwd} /USER:domain\username").WaitForExit();

Comment: @dguth8 when you are using 2 backslashes as in my example  $"C:\\{folder}", what you are telling to C# is to escape the \ and use it as part of the sequence on your string, if you do not use an escaped character for the backslash it will result in a compilation error: A character may only be escaped by doubling ... in an interpolated string. My point is that you need to construct your sequence path including those escaped characters to have the final result

Answer (score 1):

C# 6.0 introduced *string interpolation*, which is used by prefixing a quoted string of text with the `$` character.

e.g.

```
var i = 0;
var s = $"i = {i}";
// output: i = 0
```

You can also embed multiple interpolated strings, as well as conditions.

```
var i = 0;
var s = $"i is: {(i == 1 ? $"i is {1}" : "i is not 1")}";
```

This can be combined with *string literals* that are prefixed with `@`.

```
var i = 1;
var s = @$"c:\{i}\test";
```

Basically, you can write almost any normal `expression statement` in a interpolated string, such as calling methods:

```
var s = $"i is {GetValueOfI() - 100}";
```

For types that are not a `System.String`, the implementation of that types `ToString()` method will be used for the resulting value.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Thanks, reminds me a little of angular. When combining string literals does the $ sign always come second (i.e.; after the @ symbol), or does it not matter?